# Fastest Way to "De-List" an Entire Column of a Pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a pandas DF that is hundreds of thousands, potentially millions long-term, of rows.  One column is like this

```
 target_col
 [bob, had, a, baby]
 [it's, a, boy]
```

What I want though is for each row to just be a string.  Is the fastest I can do

```
df.target_col = df.target_col.apply( lambda x : " ".join(x))
```

Or is there something that is better than this?

Comment: You can avoid the lambda and just use `.apply(' '.join)` but apart from that, if you want your column as a space delimited string column... that's probably about the only thing you can do.

Comment: If there's some process that generated this database for you that will run again in the future, you might consider trying to fix the problem there instead.

Comment: Or maybe: `df['target_col'].str.join(' ')` but not sure if that'd have any performance gain although it'd have different behaviour in terms of raising exceptions or returning NaNs than the `.apply(' '.join)`